# Await inside for loop is admitted in Dart?

Tags: for-loop, dart, async-await

I have a program like the following:

```
main() async {
  ooClass = new OoClass(1);
  int val = await function1();
  print(val);
  ooClass = new OoClass(2);
  val = await function1();
  print(val);
  ooClass = new OoClass(3);
  val = await function1();
  print(val);

}

OoClass ooClass;

Future<int> function1() async {
  List list3 = await function2();
  return list3.indexOf('Ok');
}


Future<List<String>> function2() async {

  List<String> list1 = new List<String>();

  function3(Map<String, int> map1) async {
    String string1 = '';
    bool bool1 = false;
    List<String> list2 = [];
    String string2;

    function4(String string3) async {
      if (ooClass.function7(string3)) return;
      if (ooClass.function8() && !bool1) {
        bool1 = true;
        return;
      }
      string2 = await function5(string3);
      list2.add(string2);
    }

    for (String key in map1.keys) {
      await function4(key);
    }
    string1 = list2.join(', ');
    list1.add(string1);
  }

  for (Map<String, int> idxList in ooClass.function6()) {
    await function3(idxList);
  }
  return list1;
}

function5(String s1) {
  return new Future.value('Ok');
}

class OoClass {

  List<Map<String, int>> map2;
  bool bool3 = false;

  OoClass(int type) {
    switch(type) {
      case 1:
        map2 = [{'Ok':1}];
        break;
      case 2:
        map2 = [{'id': 1, 'Ok':1}];
        break;
      case 3:
        map2 = [{'foo': 1, 'Ok':1}];
        bool3 = true;
        break;
    }
  }

  List<Map<String, int>> function6() {
    return map2;
  }

  bool function7(String string9) {
    if (string9 == 'id') return true;
    return false;
  }

  bool function8() {
    return bool3;
  }
}
```

This snippet works perfectly.

In my real environment, instead, when await function4(key); is called, function2 returns the list1 List (empty). Function4 call is executed later but the result of function2 is lost.

I don't really understand this behavior. Could it be a bug or await inside for loop is not to be used?
If await should not be used inside for loop how could I implement it in another way?

I'm using dart 1.22.0-dev.4 but I've tried also with older (and stable) versions and I had the same result.

---

I finally got the problem and it did not depend on `await` in a `for` loop. It was instead an error in my code.

Comment: `await` in `for` is fine. Your code example is too complex, to bother to investigate further.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes, `await` is permitted inside a `for` loop in Dart, and it will work as expected.

```
for (var o in objects) {
  await doSomething(o);
}
```

And there is even `await for` for Streams, if that's what you're looking for:

```
await for (var event in eventStream) {
  print("Event received: $event");
}
```

Your example [works correctly](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0ec1502d63ff4489fbf0245297159cc2) in DartPad. It's too complex & abstract to debug but, at least superficially, it should work. You say that the snippet doesn't work in your "real environment", though. Maybe we could help if you explained what you mean by that?

Additional tip: [take full advantage of static analysis](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/analysis-options), especially the [await_only_futures](http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/await_only_futures.html) and [unawaited_futures](http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html) linter rules. This can help you catch many bugs.

Comment: what if await doSomething(o); has another await inside? Btw it's not working in my case

Answer (score 69):

#### `List.forEach` → `Future.forEach`

If you happen to be using `.forEach()` on a `List`, this won't work:

```
someList.forEach((item) async {
  await longFunc(item);
)}
```

You'll need to use:

```
await Future.forEach<SomeType>(someList, (item) async {
  await longFunc(item);
});
```

I mistakenly thought this applied to `List.forEach` until finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48975728/2301224).

#### Example

As per comments: add the ***List Type*** if needed.

```
  List<String> names = ['billy', 'joe'];
  
  Future.forEach<String>(names, (name) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    print(name);
  });
```

Comment: Note that while this is the best approach, the compiler won't know the type of `item` within the block. So you may have to call `await Future.forEach<TypeOfSomeList>(someList, (item) async {`

Comment: Thank you @DavidChopin -- I was getting an error like `The property 'property' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').` because I wasn't specifying the type in this way, and whatever the default is can be null ... I think this would have take a LONG time to figure out if I hadn't already seen your suggestion of a code tidy up here.  Adding this comment in case the SEO brings others here.