# How to Async/await in List.forEach() in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, foreach

I'm writing some kind of bot (command line application) and I'm having trouble with async execution when I'm using the "forEach" method.
Here is a simplified code of what I'm trying to do :

```
main() async {
  print("main start");
  await asyncOne();
  print("main end");
}

asyncOne() async {
  print("asyncOne start");
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(await (num) async {
    await asyncTwo(num);
  });
  print("asyncOne end");
}

asyncTwo(num) async
{
  print("asyncTwo #${num}");
}
```

And here is the output :

```
main start
asyncOne start
asyncOne end
main end
asyncTwo #1
asyncTwo #2
asyncTwo #3
```

What I'm trying to get is :

```
main start
asyncOne start
asyncTwo #1
asyncTwo #2
asyncTwo #3
asyncOne end
main end
```

If someone knows what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate it.

Comment: Asynchronous calls don't work with `<List>.forEach()`, you need to use traditional loops. Why? [This article](https://www.coreycleary.me/why-does-async-await-in-a-foreach-not-actually-await/) explains it very well. I just discovered that Dart and Node.JS are almost the same.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to achieve what you want with the `forEach` method. However it will work with a `for` loop. Example;

```
asyncOne() async {
  print("asyncOne start");
  for (num number in [1, 2, 3])
    await asyncTwo(number);
  print("asyncOne end");
}
```

Comment: That's what I was starting to think. Thank you for confirming it. I thought that "await" expression precedes whatever is surrounding it but oh well...

Answer (score 288):

You need to use Future.forEach.

```
main() async {
  print("main start");
  await asyncOne();
  print("main end");
}

asyncOne() async {
  print("asyncOne start");
  await Future.forEach([1, 2, 3], (num) async {
    await asyncTwo(num);
  });
  print("asyncOne end");
}

asyncTwo(num) async
{
  print("asyncTwo #${num}");
}
```

Comment: This should be the approved answer.

Comment: For anyone reading this, do note that this unfortunately only works for iterables.

Comment: Yesss this is so perfect on what I needed because of internet connection issues with the app. It'll load the list and add it, when it is complete, notify.

Comment: this does not work with Future.delayed in asyncTwo method. output is    main start
asyncOne start
asyncOne end
main end
asyncTwo #1
asyncTwo #2
asyncTwo #3

Comment: Note that while this is the best approach, the compiler may not know the type of `num` within the block. So you may have to call something like `await Future.forEach<int>(someIntList, (item) async {`

Answer (score 18):

You can't use `forEach` for this because it doesn't actually look at the return values of its callbacks. If they are futures, they will just be lost and not awaited.

You can either do a loop like Steven Upton suggested, or you can use `Future.wait` if you want the operations to run simultaneously, not one after the other:

```dart
asyncOne() async {
  print("asyncOne start");
  await Future.wait([1, 2, 3].map(asyncTwo));
  print("asyncOne end");
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but I'll leave here a new answer, hoping this help someone in the future.

**You can use forEach** for what you're trying to achieve by doing something like this:

```
  asyncOne() async {
  print("asyncOne start");
  await Future.forEach([1, 2, 3],(num) async {
    await asyncTwo(num);
  });
  print("asyncOne end");
}
```

Comment: That is literally a subset of what @Stephane posted above.

Answer (score 2):

use `forEach` loop even if you have created a list of custom class.

```
    lol() async {
  await Future.forEach(myListofFood,(Food food) async {
    await secondaryfuncton(food);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need iterate a Map, you can use:

```
await Future.forEach(myMap.keys, (key) async {
  final value = data[key];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of this solution, is that it can be used with `mapIndexed`

```
await Future.wait([1, 2, 3].map(  // or mapIndexed(
  (num) async {
    await asyncTwo(num);
  }));
```