# How would I put a pause in a .forEach interation

Tags: loops, dart, flutter

I am attempting to put in a pause between a forEach loop for a list.

I would have thought the timeout would cause a pause for the loop but it just seems to start 3 timers all at once. (In very quick succession.)

```
  startTimeout(int seconds) async {
    print('Timer Being called now');
    var duration = Duration(seconds: seconds);
    Timer(duration, doSomething());
  }


  startDelayedWordPrint() {
    List<String> testList = ['sfs','sdfsdf', 'sfdsf'];
    testList.forEach((value) async {
      await startTimeout(30000);
      print('Writing another word $value');
    });
  }
```

> Any idea how I might do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `await Future.delayed()` to pause for certain duration and a simple old `for(...in...){}` loop, instead of `forEach()` to iterate the values.

If `forEach()` receives async functions, each iteration call will run in a separate asynchronous context which can be reasoned about similarly to parallel code execution. Meanwhile forEach it self will return immediately without waiting until any async function to complete.

[How to Async/await in List.forEach() in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467663/async-await-in-list-foreach)

Sample:
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a57a500d4593aebe1bad0ed79376016c

```
main() async {
    List<String> testList = ['sfs','sdfsdf', 'sfdsf'];
    for(final value in testList) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      print('Writing another word $value');
    };
  }
```

Comment: Tried both for (var in list) and for (int i = 0; list.length; i+) both just trigger the timer all the time and neither allow me to use await Do you have a code sample?

Comment: That link is about async, thats not the issue. The issue is that I need a pause in each iteration.

Comment: @Yonkee added sample with `Future.delayed(<duration>)`, if this is what you're looking for?

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks