# Adding list items in a Future in flutter returns no items

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

In flutter i read from the firebase database twice.
The first code reads all references for a document found in an array.
The next code goes thru all references and loads documentdata for that reference in firebase.
When i debug, and as long i am in the forEach loop the rests array is filled.
But as soon as the forEach loop is done, the rests list is empty? How can this be?
What i want to do is continue to add data to the CustomerRestaurantsWithLunchCard = c to the list of restaraunts that exist in the class

```
  Future<CustomerRestaurantsWithLunchCard>
      customerRestaurantsWithLunchards() async {
    var c = await _service.document(
        path: APIPath.customerRestaurantsWithLunchCardsDocument(customerId),
        builder: (data, id) =>
            CustomerRestaurantsWithLunchCard.fromMap(data, id));

    var rests = new List<Restaurant>();

    c.myRestaurantsReferences.forEach((reference) {
      _service.document(
          path: (reference),
          builder: (data, id) => {
                rests.add(new Restaurant(
                  id: id,
                )),
              });
    });

    c.restaurants = rests;
    return c;
  }

Future<T> document<T>({
    @required String path,
    @required T builder(Map<String, dynamic> data, String id),
  }) {
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
    final snapshots = reference.get();
    return snapshots.then((value) => builder(value.data(), value.id));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in another thread [Async/Await List.forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467663/async-await-in-list-foreach)

The new code is:

```
  Future<CustomerRestaurantsWithLunchCard>
      customerRestaurantsWithLunchards() async {
    var c = await _service.document(
        path: APIPath.customerRestaurantsWithLunchCardsDocument(customerId),
        builder: (data, id) =>
            CustomerRestaurantsWithLunchCard.fromMap(data, id));

    int noOfReferences = c.myRestaurantsReferences.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < noOfReferences; i++) {
      await _service.document(
          path: c.myRestaurantsReferences[i],
          builder: (data, id) => {c.restaurants.add(new Restaurant(id: id))});
    }
return c;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add wait to second _service.document in foreach:

```
Future<CustomerRestaurantsWithLunchCard>
      customerRestaurantsWithLunchards() async {
    var c = await _service.document(
        path: APIPath.customerRestaurantsWithLunchCardsDocument(customerId),
        builder: (data, id) =>
            CustomerRestaurantsWithLunchCard.fromMap(data, id));

    List<Restaurant> rests = await new List<Restaurant>(); 
    await c.myRestaurantsReferences.forEach((reference) {
      await _service.document(
          path: (reference),
          builder: (data, id) => {
                rests.add(new Restaurant(
                  id: id,
                )),
              });
    });

    c.restaurants = await rests;
    return c;
  }
```

Comment: That did not wok, same result.

Comment: What about adding await to everything to make the function syncronous but return the future ?

Comment: as I know in async function every line of instruction is executed asyncronously so...

Comment: so `awaiting` for every line will result in synchronous behaviour