# flutter async await understanding problem

Tags: sqlite, flutter, asynchronous, async-await

I have a function as follows. All my GamePlayers are getting updated with the counter value of 1 - because the counter variable is updated after all update statements have completed.

Why is this like that and what can i do to make the counter increment each time a update query is done?

```
Future<bool> closeGame(List<GamePlayer> sortedWinnerList, Game game) async {
try {
  int counter = 1;
  await _database.transaction((txn) async {
    sortedWinnerList.forEach((element) async {
      print('xx update gamePlayer, counter= $counter');
      await txn.execute(
          'update $tableName_GAMEPLAYER set result_position = $counter where id=${element.id}');
      GameResult newResult = new GameResult(
          gameId: game.id,
          playerId: element.playerId,
          amount: element.gameWinAmount);
      await txn.insert(tableName_GAMERESULT, newResult.toJson());
      print('xx loop end, counter= $counter');
      counter++;
    });
    await txn.execute(
        'update $tableName_GAME set ended = ${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}');
  });

  return true;
} catch (e) {
  print('Game not closed: $e');
}

return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: here's another relevant question: [Async/await in List.forEach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467663/async-await-in-list-foreach)

All the functions in `forEach` are spawned when counter was 1. They don't wait for each other.

If you want them to happen one after the other, you can do a regular loop and do an `await` in it.

Here's one step towards that goal. Might even just work.

```
Future<bool> closeGame(List<GamePlayer> sortedWinnerList, Game game) async {
try {
  int counter = 1;
  await _database.transaction((txn) async {
    for (final element in sortedWinnerList) {
      print('xx update gamePlayer, counter= $counter');
      await txn.execute(
          'update $tableName_GAMEPLAYER set result_position = $counter where id=${element.id}');
      GameResult newResult = new GameResult(
          gameId: game.id,
          playerId: element.playerId,
          amount: element.gameWinAmount);
      await txn.insert(tableName_GAMERESULT, newResult.toJson());
      print('xx loop end, counter= $counter');
      counter++;
    }
    await txn.execute(
        'update $tableName_GAME set ended = ${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}');
  });

  return true;
} catch (e) {
  print('Game not closed: $e');
}

return false;
```

Comment: It is exactly like explained in the answer, a simple for loop awaits the update query and increments the counter!