# How to await a Map.forEach() in dart

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, asynchronous

I have a Future which returns a map. I then need to use the values of that map to await another future and then return the entire result at the end. The problem is that dart can't await `async` `Map.forEach()` methods (see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42467822/15782390).

Here is my code:

the debug console shows that the items printed are in the following order:

```
flutter: getting journal entries
flutter: about to loop through pictures
flutter: getting picture
flutter: returning entries
flutter: [[....]] (Uint8List)
```

```dart
Future<List<JournalEntryData>> getJournalEntries() async {
    List<JournalEntryData> entries = [];
    print('getting journal entries');

    EncryptService encryptService = EncryptService(uid);

    await journal.get().then((document) {
      Map data = (document.data() as Map);
      print('about to loop through pictures');
      data.forEach((key, value) async {
        print('getting picture');
        dynamic pictures = await StorageService(uid).getPictures(key);
        print('done getting image');
        entries.add(JournalEntryData(
          date: key,
          entryText: encryptService.decrypt(value['entryText']),
          feeling: value['feeling'],
          pictures: pictures,
        ));
      });
    });
    print('returning entries');
    return entries;
  }
```

```dart
  Future getPictures(String entryID) async {
    try {
      final ref = storage.ref(uid).child(entryID);
      List<Uint8List> pictures = [];

      await ref.listAll().then((result) async {
        for (var picReference in result.items) {
          Uint8List? pic = await ref.child(picReference.name).getData();
          if (pic == null) {
            // TODO make no picture found picture
            var url = Uri.parse(
                'https://www.salonlfc.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/image-not-found-scaled-1150x647.png');
            var response = await http.get(url);
            pic = response.bodyBytes;
          }
          pictures.add(pic);
        }
      });
      return pictures;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return e;
    }
  }
```

Comment: As explained by the question you linked to, you should use `Future.wait`.  Or see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719805/.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, it did. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix the use of `then` and `await` since it get rather confusing and things are no longer being executed as you think.
Also, the use of `forEach` method should really not be used for complicated logic like what you are doing. Instead, use the for-each loop. I have tried rewrite `getJournalEntries` here:

```
Future<List<JournalEntryData>> getJournalEntries() async {
  List<JournalEntryData> entries = [];
  print('getting journal entries');

  EncryptService encryptService = EncryptService(uid);

  final document = await journal.get();
  Map data = (document.data() as Map);
  print('about to loop through pictures');

  for (final mapEntry in data.entries) {
    final key = mapEntry.key;
    final value = mapEntry.value;

    print('getting picture');
    dynamic pictures = await StorageService(uid).getPictures(key);
    print('done getting image');
    entries.add(JournalEntryData(
      date: key,
      entryText: encryptService.decrypt(value['entryText']),
      feeling: value['feeling'],
      pictures: pictures,
    ));
  }
  print('returning entries');
  return entries;
}
```

And `getPictures` here. I have only removed the use of `then` here.

```
Future getPictures(String entryID) async {
  try {
    final ref = storage.ref(uid).child(entryID);
    List<Uint8List> pictures = [];
    final result = await ref.listAll();

    for (var picReference in result.items) {
      Uint8List? pic = await ref.child(picReference.name).getData();
      if (pic == null) {
        // TODO make no picture found picture
        var url = Uri.parse(
            'https://www.salonlfc.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/image-not-found-scaled-1150x647.png');
        var response = await http.get(url);
        pic = response.bodyBytes;
      }
      pictures.add(pic);
    }
    return pictures;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    return e;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The code does look cleaner now. Thanks for the help! It also fixed my problem! Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

It's quite annoying to have to use for-loops when you need async behaviour, specially on Maps, because as the other answer shows, that requires you to iterate over entries and then take the `key` and `value` out of it like this:

```dart
for (final mapEntry in data.entries) {
    final key = mapEntry.key;
    final value = mapEntry.value;
    ...
}
```

Instead of that, you can write a utility extension that does the work for you:

```dart
extension AsyncMap<K, V> on Map<K, V> {
  Future<void> forEachAsync(FutureOr<void> Function(K, V) fun) async {
    for (var value in entries) {
      final k = value.key;
      final v = value.value;
      await fun(k, v);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can use that like this:

```dart
await data.forEachAsync((key, value) async {
    ...
});
```

Much better.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That does seem like a more elegant solution. I hope dart by default allows for something similar in the `Future`, pun intended.