# List is Empty (Flutter)

Tags: list, flutter, arraylist

I am creating a List in Flutter and displaying it in a Column, When I Run it is just Empty and when I print the list it just prints an Array

```
I/flutter (24613): []
```

I am using this code to create the List:-

```
 myFunction() {
  return StreamBuilder(
  stream:
      users.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).limit(30).snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
 List<UserList> usersList = [];
    snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
     User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
       UserList userList = UserList(user);
       usersList.add(userList);
    });
    return Column (children: usersList);
   }
  ),
 }
```

This is My User Class:-

```
class User {

final String id;
final String username;
final String email;
final String photoUrl;


User({
  this.id,
  this.username,
  this.email,
  this.photoUrl,
});

factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
   return User(
   id: doc.data()['id'],
   username: doc.data()['username'],
   email: doc.data()['email'],
   photoUrl: doc.data()['photoUrl'],

    );
  }
}
```

The Code Is Showing No Errors and the Column Is not Displaying, Also When I print The length of the List it Shows it is Zero:-

```
I/flutter (24613): 0
```

What Could be The problem ??

Comment: where this part come from? snapshot.data.documents I believe that it doesn't have data in snapshot data so they don't loop inside to add it. You can print it out that if it's really have data inside

Comment: Where exactly you are calling this `snapshot.data.documents.` ?

Comment: @SaiPrashanth , it seems the way you are calling the `FutureBuilder` under `build` may be the issue ? Can you share the minimum `build` method implementation ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan I Switched From Future Builder To StreamBuilder and I Shared some code...Hope it helps

Comment: I have posted my answer. Let me know if that is useful. @SaiPrashanth

Comment: Can you also show the `UserList` class in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we need to tweak some of your code little bit to make the logic working. :)

`builder` param should be specified with Type otherwise it will be of type `dynamic`. To be in safer side in this case it will be `QuerySnapshot`. So,

`builder: (context, snapshot)` in your code becomes

`builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot)`.

Next, there is no need of looping through `foreach` and instead you can try something like below.

```
snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {     ....    }
```

`snapshot.data.documents` in your code is not valid way of getting the Firestore Documents. Please refer [official doc](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore)

**And you need to return a `widget` from `builder` which you have done correctly. But, by mistake you are passing the `List<UserList>` to `Column` which will be expecting `List<Widget>`**

`return Column (children: usersList);`

Here I can see you are passing `usersList` which is of type `List<UserList>`. So you can replace `Column` with `ListView` or similar kind of other `widget` since, `Column` doesn't support `scroll`.

> **So combining all these bits and pieces you will get the below snippet.**

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .limit(30)
      .snapshots(),  // Just for simplicity. 
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    //When there is no data returned from the firebase.
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
        return Text("Title: " + document['username']);
      }).toList(),
    );
  },
);
```

For simplicity, I have returned the `Text` widget. You can implement your own UI there.

**NOTE :** This is the basic working example and you need to fine tune accordingly like using model classes instead of directly accessing based on your requirements.

**Your Code**

```
 myFunction() {
  return StreamBuilder(
  stream:
      users.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).limit(30).snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
 List<UserList> usersList = [];
    snapshot.data.documents.forEach((doc) {
     User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
       UserList userList = UserList(user);
       usersList.add(userList);
    });
    return Column (children: usersList);
   }
  ),
 }
```

Comment: I Tried This and it still doesn't work, also when I Print snapshot I get the message "AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>(ConnectionState.active, Instance of 'QuerySnapshot', null, null)"

Comment: You are supposed to print the `snapshot.data`  to know the data coming in `Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'`.  Even then if data is not returned, please check the collection properties  of `Firebase` you are accessing to get the `userList`.

Comment: I tried Printing snapshot.data and I got the message "Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'." But the List is still not Showing..what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: Instead of UI. try to use `async`/`await` to get the data from firebase in a seperate function and see if that is working. You can refer this tutorial as well
https://medium.com/quick-code/reading-lists-from-firestore-using-streambuilder-in-flutter-eda590f461ed

Comment: I think I solved the issue after reading the medium tutorial I think I had a problem with the orderBy method I removed it and it worked, Thanks for the Help...

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have to await for the json to actually get parse to the dart model. Second thing is forEach method is synchronous it doesn't wait for the async operation to complete, this is the reason why your list is empty.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467663/how-to-async-await-in-list-foreach-in-dart) SO question has lot of different ways to make a list work asynchronously in flutter.

Comment: I have made forEach Async But where am I supposed to add the await...

Comment: try `User user = await User.fromDocument(doc);` and let me know if it worked

Comment: No, it does not work it gives the Message " 'await' applied to 'User', which is not a 'Future'."

Answer (score 0):

Column shows data before fetching data, so it shows empty list. For this use setstate according to your state management type ("notifylisteners" in provider) after getting data, so by this the screen will be updated and column also shows the updated list.

Answer (score 0):

As 'Ashutosh patole' said, 'forEach' method does not wait iteration's complete.
I think that because of this reason, although you made a 'usersList',
there is no data when build widget in 'usersList'.

To fix this, you'd better change from 'forEach' to 'for'.

```
void main() async {
  List<String> data = [ 'a', 'b', 'c'];
  List<String> result = [];
  data.forEach((data) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    result.add(data);
    });
  print(result);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  print(result);
  
  print('-----------------');
  
  result = [];
  for (var item in data) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    result.add(item);
  }
  print(result);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  print(result);
}
```

[image]

In your code, you can change like below.

```
List<UserList> usersList = [];
for (var doc in snapshot.data.documents) {
    User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
    UserList userList = UserList(user);
    usersList.add(userList);
}
```

Comment: It Does Not Work it just gives the Error "Undefined name 'doc'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name."

Comment: I changed that 'var' added front of doc.

Comment: Any alternate Solutions ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure how you're handling the scope of the variable.
Here's my minimal reproducible code which can give you some idea on how to add the items to the list.

```dart
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  final List<Widget> _list = [FlutterLogo()];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      if (timer.tick >= 2) timer.cancel();
      setState(() => _list.add(FlutterLogo()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: _list),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the data, check all fields:

[Firestore Docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read)

Add a `print()` to see where the problem

```dart
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        //This
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        print(snapshot.data);

        //This
        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        print(snapshot.data);

        //This
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
```

Comment: when I print snapshot.data it prints The Message "Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'".

Answer (score 0):

This is what i typically use.Try out this! Please balance the brackets in the code

```
    FutureBuilder(
                    future: users.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).limit(30),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<User>> snapshot) {
                      List<User>ulist=snapshot.data;
                        return ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25,bottom: 35),
                          itemCount: evlist==null?0:evlist.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            String evtime=evlist[index].fromdate.substring(11,16);
                            String ontime=evlist[index].fromdate.substring(0,16);
                            return Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(width: 1.8,color: Colors.indigo[900]),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                  color: Colors.grey[200]
                              ),
                              margin:
                              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0, vertical: 4.0),
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                                title: Text(ulist[index].username.toString()),
                                subtitle:Text("next data"),

                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
```

Comment: why specifically?

Comment: if you need to get the task done, the future builder is there! i don't know whats the intention of strictly sticking in to stream builder.. !