# Working with futures in a for loop flutter dart

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart, async-await, future

Whenever I call the getCurrentUserNodes() it does not wait for the for loop to complete. How can I fix this?
Here is my code:

```
class NodeCardBuilder {
  Future<List<Widget>> getCurrentUserNodes(BuildContext passedContext) async {
    List<Widget> nodeCards = [];
    List nodes = await FirebaseHelper().getNodeList();
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(passedContext).size;
    nodeCards.add(SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.2, width: size.width));

    for (Map node in nodes) {
      node.forEach((key, value) async {
        List vpsData = await VpsHelper(value['ip'], 22, 'root', value['pass'])
            .getVpsData();

        nodeCards.add(NodeCard(
          key,
          value['ethAdd'],
          double.parse(vpsData[0]) / 100,
          double.parse(vpsData[1]) / 100,
          double.parse(vpsData[2]) / 100,
        ));
        debugPrint(nodeCards.toString());
      });
    }

    return nodeCards;
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem is forEach, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467663/how-to-async-await-in-list-foreach-in-dart).

Comment: can you call await on foreach ?

Comment: I tried doing that already. How do implement future.foreach with a map