# how to show circular progress indicator while uploading multiple images to firebase using two screens

Tags: flutter, dart

i am making a house management app i have to upload images of the property alongside other data related to the property so i am using two screens one for the general info about the house and the second one specifically to upload images

**Form screen**

[image]

**Image Upload Screen**

[image]

from the upload screen i am returning back a list of images to the form screen

```
// i am waiting for the list in the form screen
images = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddPictures()));

// i am returning the list back from the upload screen
Navigator.pop(context,imageStrings);
```

I am failing to show circular progress indicator for some reason beyond my capacity to know itried all ways i know

this is the rest of the code

```
//outiside the widdget build i have two lists
List<XFile> imagesXFiles = []; //for raw image files from the gallery or camera 
List<String> imageStrings = []; //for image links from the firebase storage 

body: isLoading == true ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            //the first grid is a button to let the user access camera or gallery
            child: GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 2.0
              ),
              itemCount: imagesXFiles.length + 1,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return index == 0 ? GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    // a function to pick images and add store them to the list "imagesXFiles"
                    _showPicker(context);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 30.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ): Container(
                  child: Image(
                      image: FileImage(File(imagesXFiles[index-1].path)),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: ()async{
                // for some reason the circular progress doesn't work i dont understand why 
                setState(() {
                  isLoading = true;
                });
                imageStrings = await uploadImages(imagesXFiles).whenComplete(() {
                  setState(() {
                    isLoading = false;
                    Navigator.pop(context,imageStrings);
                  });

                });
              },
              child: Text("Upload",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 25),)),
        ],
      ),
```

here is the upload function that uploads the images to firebase

```
Future<List<String>> uploadImages(List<XFile> imagesXFiles) async {

   imagesXFiles.forEach((image) async {
    final storageRef = storage.ref().child(Random().nextInt(100).toString());
    await storageRef.putFile(File(image.path));
    String imageURL = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();

    imageStrings.add(imageURL);
    firebaseFirestore
        .collection("housePictures")
        .add({
      "imageURL" : imageURL,
    });
  });

  return imageStrings;

}
```

Comment: Is your problem that you can't see the circular indicator or does it pop too fast after tapping the button? also can you show the whole StatefulWidget of your upload screen?

tip: don't use forEach with async, it will not await

Comment: the code seem fine, you can add Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),

Comment: You can manage the loader using this package flutter_easyloading: ^3.0.5

Comment: thanks @NehilKoshiya but i prefer using no package

Comment: @EdwynZN i dont see a circular loader at all i think its the issue of foreach i will try to change it and get back here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use forEach with Future as below.

```
await Future.forEach(imagesXFiles, (image) async {
    final storageRef = storage.ref().child(Random().nextInt(100).toString());
    await storageRef.putFile(File(image.path));
    String imageURL = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();

    imageStrings.add(imageURL);
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("housePictures")
        .add({
            "imageURL" : imageURL,
         });
});
```

Comment: i am getting an error `The getter 'path' isn't defined for the type 'Object'`

Comment: i managed to make it work `await Future.forEach(imagesXFiles, (XFile image) async {...}`

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use forEach statement in an async operation. It is not going to wait. Use a normal `for` statement. Example: `for(var item in items)` etc. That should fix your issue. If you really want to use a `for each` you need to use Future. `foreach` see this thread -> [How to Async/await in List.forEach() in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467663/how-to-async-await-in-list-foreach-in-dart)