# Can't get data from a reference field in Cloud Firestore with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I have one collection called Audiolibros (audiobooks) in Cloud Firestore. Each document of this collection has one field called idAutor (idAuthor) that it's a Reference field from a collection called Autores (authors).

[Reference field in Audiolibros collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtFBA.png)

I want to get the information inside the Autores's document by the author's id saved in an Audiolibro's document. I don't mind if I have to get the author id from Audiolibros and then use it in other method to get the author information getting the document by that id, or if I can get all the content of that author in the same method, but the fact is that it's been impossible for me to get that information.

[Author's document content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEwdJ.png)

I've tried many things, but the problem is that, when I get the idAutor field, I don't get it as a DocumentReference, as I've seen in other responses, I get it as a _JsonDocumentReference. And no matter what I do, I don't know how to extract the author id from a _jsonDocumentReference. Probably it's easier than I think, but I don't know how to do it.
Anyone knows how to get the author's information from a reference field of its id?

[_JsonDocumentReference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIysE.png)

In the method I have, I want to get the author information for every audiobook in the list of audiobooks. This is one of the multiple options I've tried:

```
    Future<List<Audiolibro>> getAudiolibros() async{
    List<Audiolibro> listaAudiolibros = [];

    CollectionReference audiolibros = bbdd.collection("audiolibros");
    QuerySnapshot<Object?> response = await audiolibros.get();

    response.docs.forEach((element) {
      final data = element.data();
      final datos = data as Map<String, dynamic>;
      var rutaAutorAudiolibro = datos['idAutor'] as DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>;

      //I don't know how to continue from this point to get the author information

    });

    return listaAudiolibros;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`_JsonDocumentReference`](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_reference.dart#L96-L100) is just the class that implements `DocumentReference` in FlutterFire, so a `_JsonDocumentReference` is also a valid `DocumentReference`.
- Since `rutaAutorAudiolibro` is a `DocumentReference`, you can call `get()` on it to get the corresponding `DocumentSnapshot`.
- If you want to `await` the loading of the author, you'll need to use `for...in` or `Future.await()` rater than `forEach`.  See [How to Async/await in List.forEach() in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42467822/209103)

Comment: Yess! It was exactly that! Thank you for you answer, I'm new to Flutter and Cloud Firestore and No SQL DB and I'm a bit lost hahaha. Finally, I put the code like this:
`
    await Future.forEach(response.docs, (element) async {
          final data = element.data();
          final datos = data as Map<String, dynamic>;
          var rutaAutorAudiolibro = datos['idAutor'] as DocumentReference<Map<String, 
    dynamic>>;
          var rutaAutorSnapshot = await rutaAutorAudiolibro.get();
          final datosAutorSnapshot = rutaAutorSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
`