# Dart / Flutter: Error "Stream has already been listened to." && "await for" inside fa "for loop" fails

Tags: dart, flutter, stream, iteration

aye aye good people,

I'm probably missing something here:

this code is fictional (it's an oversimplification, for everyone convenience), but gives the idea:

```
_map.keys.forEach((key) async {
   _bloc.sink.add(_map[key]);
await for (String _string in _bloc.stream) {
  _newMap.putIfAbsent(key, ()=> _string);
 }
});
```

or

```
Stream.fromIterable(_map.keys).forEach((day) async {
    _bloc.sink.add(_map[key]);
await for (String _string in _bloc.stream) {
  _newMap.putIfAbsent(key, ()=> _string);
 }
});
```

with  StreamController<...>.broadcast();
the streams seams healthly:

> first:_Future hashCode:817453996 isBroadcast:true isEmpty:_Future
>   last:_Future length:_Future runtimeType:Type
>   (_BroadcastStream<...>) single:_Future
>   _awaiter:null
>   _generator:null
>   _controller:_AsyncBroadcastStreamController

without returns this error:

> first:Unhandled exception:\nBad state: Stream has already been
>   listened to.[...] hashCode:644468606 isBroadcast:false
>   isEmpty:Unhandled exception:\nBad state: Stream has already been
>   listened to.[...] last:Unhandled exception:\nBad state: Stream has
>   already been listened to.[...] length:Unhandled exception:\nBad state:
>   Stream has already been listened to.[...] runtimeType:Type
>   (_ControllerStream<...>) single:Unhandled exception:\nBad state:
>   Stream has already been listened to.[...] _awaiter:null
>   _generator:null _controller:_AsyncStreamController

in both cases, doesn't work.

what I intended to do is (inside a for loop) to send in the sink a collection,

a bloc will do some work and return another collection in the stream,

what I can see from debug is that the loop just keep sending stuff to the sink.

I'm not sure that is because:

...

**1)** the loop **doesn't wait for "await for"**

and causes the error "stream already listen"

**2)** vice-versa the **"await for " cannot listen to the stream** because of the error

(or because the broadcast can lose the event) therefore the loop keep looping(?);

...

I'm more incline to about the first one, but it should work according to this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41375905/await-inside-for-loop-is-admitted-in-dart)

what am I doing wrong?

thank you in advance, Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like you calling stream.listen more than once. Try to assign the _bloc.stream to a variable outside of your for loop.

```
var stream = _bloc.stream;


_map.keys.forEach((key) async {
  _bloc.sink.add(_map[key]);
await for (String _string in stream) {
 _newMap.putIfAbsent(key, ()=> _string);
}
});
```