# Waiting for stream to stop before returning List

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a StreamSubscription that correctly reads data received from my device.

```
StreamSubscription<List<int>> _rxSubscription;
List<List<int>> _response = new List<List<int>>();

_rxSubscription = _ble.subscribeToCharacteristic(_rx).listen((event) {
      _response.add(event);
    });

writeToDevice(List<int> command) async {
    _rxSubscription.resume();
    await _ble.writeCharacteristicWithoutResponse(_tx, value: command);
    return _response;
  }
```

Here is how the device responds:

```
I/flutter ( 5506): [[0, 65, 0, 0], [0, 0, 104, 220, 69, 91, 240, 63, 0, 0, 240, 100, 112, 209, 240, 63, 0, 0, 176, 19], [133, 233, 240, 63, 0, 0, 104, 126, 172, 204, 240, 63, 0, 0, 96, 250, 189, 193, 240, 63]]
```

This data is continuously streamed when any write operation is performed and can vary in length depending on the 'command' meaning there can be n number of packets which are sent back. Right now after running the function, it returns an empty list of lists since _response is returned before the device starts responding.

What I'm trying to do: Get the _response to return only after all the data is collected and the device stops responding, ie. the Stream stops streaming. How would I do this in dart? I don't want to use a timer, since the data might take longer or shorter.
(Currently there is no implementation in the packets which might indicate end of line of end of message)

Vendor Instructions:
[image: Vendor Instructions]

Comment: If there's nothing to indicate end-of-message, and if you don't want to use a timeout, how do you expect to know when the stream is done?

Comment: @jamesdlin I know, it's been eating my mind. But it is possible, I saw it in the native implementation of my device's connection library in Kotlin. I was thinking if there is a way of keeping a check on when the last response arrived + 1 second, and then send it to the consumer. That's how they did it natively.

Comment: I have updated with vendor instructions. The first packet [0,65,0,0] indicates the number of packets that are going to be received. But in their native library, they don't have such an implementation, they just wait for all messages to arrive and use the data length to validate if all is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm trying to do: Get the _response to return only after all the data is collected and the device stops responding, ie. the Stream stops streaming.

Depending on the listener's needs, this may be simplified by using a Future. Is this a broadcast stream?

Comment: It's not a broadcast. It listens to device notifications. I want it to listen to all the data that the device responds with and then store it in the _response, and after that return it. I understand that it could be a Future, but I want the final data to be received and stored because there are a number of operations that need to be performed on it.

Comment: Also, could you explain a bit of how that can be done in this context?

Comment: I see your problem. You want to consume the stream, which you're aware of how to do, but you want to cache the streamed data as well as forward it to some other consumer?

Comment: This is like trying to get an `int` from a `Future<int>` without using an `async` function. The data must be consumed as a `Stream` there is no timing or lifecycle that lets you synchronously read `List<List<int>>`.

[Have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41375905/await-inside-for-loop-is-admitted-in-dart) you may try to use that syntax to consume your stream.

Comment: Right! But I want to return the result to the consumer only when the streaming stops. The consumer starts the stream by calling the function (_rxSubscription.resume()) and will also be stopping it. The data starts streaming 2-3 seconds after the function is called.

Comment: I fixed my link in my previous comment... also keep in mind that you can `map` and `asyncMap` over `Stream`s, which allows you to run whatever function you want just before forwarding the data.